# push local gitlab site issues and comments to remote repo

Tags: gitlab

I've been using git for a little while now in a new project I am working on.

I decided to use GitLab.com as I would like the opportunity to keep me repos private until I'm ready to share them (which github doesn't allow me to do).

The whole beauty of git for me is that I have a copy of the whole repo on my local machine and on the remote site.

However I make lots of comments, on my 'local' gitlab instance.

I know that I can put the wiki into source control, is it possibly to do the same thing with the comments and milestones (or in some other way share them between repositories)

I feel that this should be possible.
Maybe using an rss feed to push and pull the data to / from the various locations.
Or can I use the issues as a 'mailing list' somehow, with a 'mail into list' (however I would then need to get my local gitlab instance to mail any new issues to the remote - could probably be setup using some form of 'auto forward' filter in my mail client / gmail.

Are any of these ideas even possible ?
Is there a better solution - I'd prefer something that will integrate into my gitlab instance (local and remote), rather than needing having to use a separate interface ~ I like everything to be in a single place if possible.
Remember also I like to have access to my issues etc when offline (and then have them 'sync' when I go back online).

Thanks for any help in advance.

David

Answer (score 0):

You could build a script and make use of the [API](http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/api/) to sync your issues and notes. Maybe a script that pulls all of the new [issues](http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/api/issues.html#list-project-issues) and [notes](http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/api/notes.html#list-project-issue-notes) and POSTs them to the equivalent projects on GitLab.com. You could run the script manually or create a cron job to post the new items periodically.